# Why is require('/routes')(app); not equivalent to having the same code in one app.js file?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The following lines of code deliver the localhost/join page.

routes.js file

```
module.exports = function (app){
        app.get("/join", function (req, res){
        res.render("join");
    });
};
```

---

app.js file

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express(); 
require('./routes')(app);
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started at localhost:3000. Ctrl+C to exit.");
});
```

---

join.ejs file

```
<h1> You can sign up here </h1>

<input type="email" placeholder="email address"> </input>
<br>
<input type="password" placeholder="password"> </input>
<br>
<input type="submit"> </input>
```

---

Yet when I try to create an `app.post()` route (which works when in the app.js file) it gives me the error

> app not defined

Why would this be given for `app.post()` and not `app.get()`? Why is `require('/routes')(app);` not equivalent to having the same code in one app.js file?

Answer (score 0):

Your app.js should look like follows:

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express()
require('./routes')(app);

app.listen(PORT-NUMBER)
```

If yes then it will helpful to know how your routes.js looks like with app.post() route.

Comment: This is how my app.js looks, edited post to show. For example, this version of routes.js gives the error "controller not defined" yet it works when in my app.js file. 

    `module.exports = function (app){
    app.post('/', controller.register);
     };`

Comment: @HenryPopiolek did you import your controller inside routes.js

Comment: excuse my ignorance but if all variables need to be imported into routes.js to make it work then what is the point in a routes.js file? Does it not just become app.js at that point?

Comment: @HenryPopiolek if you want to keep your controller reference inside app.js then you have to import controller inside app.js and pass on as a parameter to routes like  require('./routes')(app, controller) and also modify your routes.js as module.exports = function (app, controller){ app.post('/', controller.register); }. but remember anyhow you have to pass controller reference to your routes.js otherwise it'll throw controller not defined which is obvious.